# Struggling with negative lookahead in a regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I humbly request for some guidance on using multiple negative lookaheads in a regex. I currently have a string that matches up against 2 regular expressions.

String: **Armadale Joe Bloggs 22-333-222 20001 Whitfords to Butler**

1. `^Armadale\D+\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}\D+2\d{4}\D+$`
2. `(Armadale|Fremantle|Butler|Mandurah|Midland|Thornlie)\D+(?![0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2})2[0-9]{4}\D+$`

How can I modify Regex 2 so that it **doesn't** match the string?

Shouldn't the negative lookahead `(?![0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2})` NOT match **22-333-22**?

I would instead, like to have Regex 2 match **22-333-333**, **333-333-22** or **22-22-22**?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers,

Trav.

Comment: *How can I modify Regex 2 so that it doesn't match the string?* The regex doesn't match the string now https://regex101.com/r/dI3xE1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation suggests your initial sample string should be "**Armadale Joe Bloggs 22-333-22 20001 Whitfords to Butler**". I.e. having only two digits in the third digit group. So the dash-separated digit series should be of the lengths 2-3-2.

Now, what you want in your new regex is filter off the 2-3-2 series but allow for others -- 2-3-3, 3-3-2, or 2-2-2, for example. And you was close by adding the `(?![0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2})` lookahead but missed the new digit series pattern. Here's a corrected version:

```
^(Armadale|Fremantle|Butler|Mandurah|Midland|Thornlie)\D+(?![0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}\D+)\d+-\d+-\d+\D+2[0-9]{4}\D+$
```

(Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vI0tY3/1)

In the regex above I used generic `\d+-\d+-\d+` pattern which you may wish make more restrictive, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, Dimtry. Can you kindly explain why the new digit series pattern \d+-\d+-\d+ is required because I still can't seem to wrap my head around it?

Comment: @sdpl.cs: This pattern is required to match 22-333-333, 333-333-22, 22-22-22, or any other sequence of dash-delimited numbers. The point is that  the `(?![0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}\D+)` pattern does not really match anything. It just restricts the previous part (i.e. `(Armadale|Fremantle|Butler|Mandurah|Midland|Thornlie)\D+`) so that it should be followed by "22-333-22" or anything like that.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. In addition to that, how would I modify the regex so that it's flexible enough to cater to the string 'Armadale Sam Bloggs GIBBERISH GIBERISH Whitfords to Butler' and basically anything that isn't \d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2} & 2\d{4} between 'Sam Bloggs and Whitfords to Butler'?

Comment: `^.*?Sam Bloggs.*?Whitfords to Butler$` for anything between "Bloggs" and "Whitfords" (https://regex101.com/r/hE0mP1/2) or `^.*?Sam Bloggs\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+Whitfords to Butler$` for any two "words" (i.e. non-space sequences) between "Bloggs" and "Whitfords" (https://regex101.com/r/sK8vF3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is not working because you are checking for a XX-XXX-XX substring after current position in the regex, and the subsequent characters are 5 digits, which means the look-ahead will always be true. Remove the look-ahead and you will match `Armadale Joe Bloggs 20001 Whitfords to Butler`, not `Armadale Joe Bloggs 22-333-222 20001 Whitfords to Butler` (which your current regex does not match because you disallow the digit to appear before the `2`):

```
(Armadale|Fremantle|Butler|Mandurah|Midland|Thornlie)[^\d\n]+2[0-9]{4}[^\d\n]+$
```

See [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/tC8dH6/2)

If you want to grab any XX(X)-XX(X)-XX(X) digit/hyphen sequences, use

```
\b[0-9]{2,3}(?:-[0-9]{2,3}){2}\b
```

See [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/tC8dH6/1)

You may combine the regexps to match both the strings with alternatives and the digit-hyphen sequences:

```
(Armadale|Fremantle|Butler|Mandurah|Midland|Thornlie)[^\d\n]+2[0-9]{4}[^\d\n]+$|\b[0-9]{2,3}(?:-[0-9]{2,3}){2}\b
```

See [demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/tC8dH6/3)